# Can you blood bend Trees in Avatar?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

Bloodbending is the subcategory of Waterbending and Bloodbending works by...

> **Bending the water in another to control them like a puppet**

We know you can bend water in animals and people. My question is

1. What are the exceptions to this and could you bloodbend a tree? I want a somewhat openminded  answer and please don't tell me this is silly to think of a question like this!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, it wouldn't be called bloodbending since trees don't have blood. However, bending plants has been done before by members of the [Foggy Swamp Tribe](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Foggy_Swamp_Tribe) such [as Huu](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Huu). They tend to bend soft plants like vines and seaweed that are "highly saturated with water". I don't recall them being able to bend trees, but presumably that's because the stiffness of the wood and the lack of water would make it impractical.

Comment: In the episode that bloodbending was introduced, when Katara fought the old lady who was trying to teach her blood bending, They sucked the water out of the trees and plants around them (causing them to shrivel).  This is much the same.

Comment: I decided to leave that incident out because the OP specifically wants instances where the water bender controls the plant *like a puppet*.

Comment: It raised an interesting question though: could a Waterbender pick up an entire tree by the water inside and chuck it at people? Because while it would be funny and possibly rather effective I think this is not entirely in line with the concepts of Waterbending.